# Does requiring a module that requires the same file cause issues in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've got some serverless functions running on firebase functions, and I'm getting some strange issues which I think maybe relating to how I'm using modules in Node.js

I have a file that deals just with anything to do with a user

users.js

```
const { updateAudioDoc } = require('./audio')

const getUser(id) => {
   // get user document
}

const addUserStatistics = {
   // some code
   updateAudioDoc()
}

module.exports = {
   getUser
}
```

I then have another file which just deals with audio

audio.js

```
...
const { getUser } = require('./users')

const addAudioToUser = id {
   // some code
   getUser(id)
}

module.exports = {
   addUserToAudio
}
```

With a structure like this, the `users.js` file is requesting the `audio.js` file, which in turns requests the `users.js`.

I'm receiving some errors like `getUser() is not a function`. I'm wondering if this is because of this way I've structured modules?

Comment: You've created a circular dependency by the sounds of it (`users` loads `audio` which internally loads `users`)

Comment: It's explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles). You can try to load `require('./users')` in `adudio.js` from `setTimeout`.